# capture executed sql from input table in pentaho pdi

Tags: testing, pentaho

I am using pentaho for data migration testing. I have set a "table input" step where many parts of the query inside "table inputs" are variables. I have been looking for a way to capture that query after it gets executed during runtime. 
I was wondering if there is any specific system log variables for sql or is it to do with metadata. need help!  Thanks

Comment: Kettle has some automatic logging mechanism that you may be able to use. I'm afraid you will have to describe your requirements in a more detailed fashion. Also, we need to know what excatly you mean by *many parts of the query inside "table inputs" are variables*.

Comment: I just want to capture the executed sql and insert that sql into a my own custom log table.

Comment: Are you thinking of a dynamically generated SQL statement? As far as I know the SQL statements in Kettle are usually static.

Comment: example in input table step i would have this query: select ${column_names} from emp; so this column_name variable will be set from previous transformation. now when this sql gets executed i need a way to capture that sql only.

Comment: In this case it would suffice to expand the string, wouldn't it?

Comment: yeah but i need to capture the query when its executed. that way i dont have to do it for other similar steps.

Comment: Where would you like to use the captured SQL statement? Why is the timing important?

Comment: timing is important cause my log should be able to show only what really got executed. I thought there was some way using jacascript or java. i found some guy using Meta object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the following approach will help:

- We assume a transformation reading a CSV file to get the dynamic portion of the SELECT statement (e.g. the columns) and setting the variable `columns` with it.

[image]

- The second transformation uses this variable to generate the SELECT statement and store it into the variable `sql_statement`.

[image]

- In the main transformation we use `${sql_statement}` as the SELECT statement of the table input and write the data to an output file (that's the business process so to say). From the same input we *copy* the output to another path. There we add the current time as a field (use element "Get system data") and we add the generated SQL statement, join them as a cartesian product and group the result by the `sql_statement`. That way we can compute the first time and the last time that the statement was used. These results are written to a text file.

[image]

- The last thing we need is a job calling the three transformations sequentially.

[image]

This is a sample output:

```
sql_statement;min_time;max_time
SELECT my_column FROM test_table;2014/05/08 00:41:21.143;2014/05/08 00:41:21.144
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Marcus! I did some thing similar. 
It works. awesome. 
I gathered parts of queries from table field where they were kept and formed a full query in javascript. After that full query will be sent  as parameter to a transformation that will run and log the query.